# I have problems creating and showing the panel in the class MyPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am working on an Uni Project using Java Swing. I want to create a statistics panel containing Temperature and other variables.

I have problems creating and showing the  panel in the class `MyPanel`.
When I replace `MyPanel p = new MyPanel()` in the Class Main with the content of the method `paintComponent` in the Class `MyPanel` it works but not the other way around . I want to create the panel in a separate class and just call on it.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JPanel p = createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

    private static JPanel createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
        SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
       
        MyPanel p = new MyPanel(); 

        f.add(p);
        //f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        return p;
    } 
}
```

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel TemperaturLabel ;
    private JTextField Temperatur ;
    private JLabel LuftfeuchtigkeitLabel;
    private JTextField Luftfeuchtigkeit;
    private JLabel luftdruckLabel;
    private JTextField luftdruck;
    private JLabel VorhersageLabel; 
    private JPanel Panel;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        TemperaturLabel = new JLabel("Temperatur: ");
        Temperatur = new JTextField(2);

        LuftfeuchtigkeitLabel  = new JLabel("Luftfeuchtigkeit: ");
        Luftfeuchtigkeit  = new JTextField(3);

        luftdruckLabel = new JLabel("Luftdruck: ");
        luftdruck = new JTextField(4);

        Panel= new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());

        VorhersageLabel = new JLabel("Vorhersage:------"); 

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets= new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        Panel.add(TemperaturLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=1;
        Panel.add(Temperatur,c);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        Panel.add(LuftfeuchtigkeitLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=2;
        Panel.add(Luftfeuchtigkeit,c);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        Panel.add(luftdruckLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=3;
        Panel.add(luftdruck,c);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        Panel.add(VorhersageLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=4;
    } 

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(900,700);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You extend a JPanel and use a JPanel in MyPanel.  Just use a JPanel.  2) The paintComponent method of a JPanel is used for custom painting using Graphics methods.  Your code can go in an ordinary method, like createAndShowPanel.  3) It's a whole lot easier to visually debug your Swing code if you create Swing components in column, row order.  You define a JLabel in one place and add it to the JPanel in a different place.  It's visually confusing.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're expecting to see something like this?

[image]

There were a number of logical errors in that code that caused a number of problems. Here is the corrected code with comments on most of them. (Some were not fixed as they did not make much difference in the end.)

The fundamental problem came from both extending and creating an instance of the `JPanel`. What ended up in the frame was the extended panel to which nothing had been added!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// Use meaningful names for classes, attributes and methods!
// Don't. Extend. JFrame! 
// public class Main extends JFrame {
public class MyPanelDisplayProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // See comments below
                // JPanel p = createAndShowGUI();
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    // why is this method returning anything? It makes no sense to do that.
    // private static JPanel createAndShowGUI() {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "
                + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Oh my! This clashes with another name in my 'junk code' package!
        // Again. Descriptive names!
        // MyPanel p = new MyPanel();
        WeatherPanel p = new WeatherPanel();

        f.add(p.getPanel());
        //f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

/* Don't extend panels either, unless custom painting. */
//class WeatherPanel extends JPanel {
class WeatherPanel {    

    /*
     *  Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. 
    `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, 
    `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) 
    and use it consistently.
     */
    private JLabel TemperaturLabel ;
    private JTextField Temperatur ;
    private JLabel LuftfeuchtigkeitLabel;
    private JTextField Luftfeuchtigkeit;
    private JLabel luftdruckLabel;
    private JTextField luftdruck;
    private JLabel VorhersageLabel; 
    private JPanel Panel;

    /*
    The resoning here is entirely wrong. Components should be created and 
    added from within a constructor!
    */
    // protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    public WeatherPanel() {
        TemperaturLabel = new JLabel("Temperatur: ");
        Temperatur = new JTextField(2);

        LuftfeuchtigkeitLabel  = new JLabel("Luftfeuchtigkeit: ");
        Luftfeuchtigkeit  = new JTextField(3);

        luftdruckLabel = new JLabel("Luftdruck: ");
        luftdruck = new JTextField(4);

        Panel= new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());

        VorhersageLabel = new JLabel("Vorhersage:------"); 

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets= new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        Panel.add(TemperaturLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=1;
        Panel.add(Temperatur,c);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        Panel.add(LuftfeuchtigkeitLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=2;
        Panel.add(Luftfeuchtigkeit,c);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        Panel.add(luftdruckLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=3;
        Panel.add(luftdruck,c);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        Panel.add(VorhersageLabel,c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=4;
    } 
    
    // Now to get the panel that is created, we can add a 'get panel' method. 
    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return Panel;
    }

    /**
     * This is both unnecessary and counterproductive. 
     * See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size 
     * methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  
     * (Yes.)
     */
    /*
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(900,700);
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, rearranged it, and added a few things to get this GUI.

[image: Swing Demo]

I redid your `createAndShowGUI` method to remove the static and use a new `getPanel` method I created.

I redid your `TemperaturePanel` class to create and show a `JPanel`.  I organized your Swing components in column, row order so I could visually verify the Swing components.  I added the missing `JTextField`.  I created getter methods so you could actually get and set the values in the `JTextFields`.

I formatted the code and used proper camelCase variable names.

Here's the revised code.  I made the `TemperaturePanel` an inner class so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TemperatureGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TemperatureGUI().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? " + 
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TemperaturePanel p = new TemperaturePanel();
        f.add(p.getPanel());
        // f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class TemperaturePanel {

        private JTextField temperatur;
        private JTextField luftfeuchtigkeit;
        private JTextField luftdruck;
        private JTextField vorhersage;

        private JPanel panel;
        
        public TemperaturePanel() {
            this.panel = createAndShowPanel();
        }
        
        private JPanel createAndShowPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.anchor =  GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 1.0;
            c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            JLabel temperaturLabel = new JLabel("Temperatur: ");
            panel.add(temperaturLabel, c);

            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            temperatur = new JTextField(10);
            panel.add(temperatur, c);

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            JLabel luftfeuchtigkeitLabel = new JLabel("Luftfeuchtigkeit: ");
            panel.add(luftfeuchtigkeitLabel, c);

            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 2;
            luftfeuchtigkeit = new JTextField(10);
            panel.add(luftfeuchtigkeit, c);

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 3;
            JLabel luftdruckLabel = new JLabel("Luftdruck: ");
            panel.add(luftdruckLabel, c);

            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 3;
            luftdruck = new JTextField(10);
            panel.add(luftdruck, c);

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 4;
            JLabel vorhersageLabel = new JLabel("Vorhersage:------");
            panel.add(vorhersageLabel, c);

            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 4;
            vorhersage = new JTextField(10);
            panel.add(vorhersage, c);

            return panel;
        }

        public JTextField getTemperatur() {
            return temperatur;
        }

        public JTextField getLuftfeuchtigkeit() {
            return luftfeuchtigkeit;
        }

        public JTextField getLuftdruck() {
            return luftdruck;
        }

        public JTextField getVorhersage() {
            return vorhersage;
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }

}
```